# On the set of cusps $\mathbb{P^1(Q)}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-actions, modular-forms

The following is from the book *Modular Forms* by W Stein:

[image]

My questions:

$1-$ The very same book defines *a cusp form* as a modular form when $f(\infty)=a_0=0$. Is *the set of cusps* a different concept irrelevant to a cusp form? Otherwise how $\mathbb{P^1(Q)}$ is a cusp form?

$2-$ By the book *Algebra* by P Aluffi, the orbit of $a ∈ A$ under an action of a group $G$ is the set $O_G(a):={\{g.a | g∈G }\}$. So $$C(\Gamma)={\{\gamma.q \ | \ \gamma∈\Gamma, \forall q ∈\mathbb{Q}\cup{\infty} }\} = {\{\ \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d} \ | \ \text{matrix [a,b,c,d]} ∈\Gamma, z ∈\mathbb{Q}\cup{\infty} }\}.$$ Is that right? (Sorry I couldn't right matrix 2*2 in latex)

$3-$ With definition on $Q.2$ (if it is right) :

$a)$ how $C(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))={\{ [\infty] }\}$?!  and,

$b)$ does ${\{ [\infty] }\}={\{ \infty }\}$ mean?

$4-$ How the lemma is related to the set/equality in $Q.3$? That is, how the (proof of the) lemma implies $C(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))={\{ [\infty] }\}$?

Comment: $G_4(z) = \sum_{n,m} \frac{1}{(nz+m)^4}$ is a modular form but it isn't holomorphic at the cusp of $X$ ($X$ is $Y = H/SL_2(Z)$ plus the point at $i\infty$). For congruence subgroups $H/\Gamma$ is a Riemann surfaces and it becomes a compact Riemann surface after adding finitely many points. Compact Riemann surfaces are more interesting because there are no holomorphic non-constant functions so the meromorphic functions are defined by their zeros/poles. Also they are (isomorphic to) algebraic curves.

Comment: ... I meant at the cusp of $Y$. Do you see why $Y$ is a Riemann surface and why it is possible to add one point to it to obtain a compact Riemann surface ? $f$ is "meromorphic on $X$" iff $f \circ \varphi_m$ is meromorphic in the usual sense for $m \in 1 \ldots, 4$. What are the $\varphi_m$ ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Cusp forms are distinguished by their behavior at cusps. $\infty$ is a cusp. Moreover, because modular forms transform in a particular way under the action of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, describing the behavior of a modular form at $\infty$ implies things about its behavior at every other cusp as well.
2. No. What your notation describes is just all of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q})$. The definition refers to the set of orbits.
3. $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q})$, so the action consists of a single orbit. The parenthetical says: "we will often identify elements of $C(\Gamma)$ with a representative element from the orbit." So the notation $\{ [\infty] \}$ means: there is one orbit, which is the orbit represented by (containing) $\infty$.
4. The lemma says precisely that the action is transitive.

Comment: Could you explain (as simple as possible!) how $C(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))={\{ [\infty] }\}?$? The book Aluffi doesn't define orbit for an element of a set and I don't know $C(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ means at all. I know little Algebra and am very new in Modular Forms

Comment: I think you need to spend some time studying basic group theory before you're ready to study modular forms. Any textbook on group theory should explain what an orbit is and what it means to consider the set of orbits of a group action.

Comment: I wrote the definition of an orbit on an element in OP but I don't know the set-definition for $C(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$. I understood the other sections of your answer. I mean could you write $C(\Gamma) = {\{ ...}\}$ (as a set)

Comment: Do you know what it means to consider the set of equivalence classes under an equivalence relation? (If not, you really should learn that before learning about modular forms.) An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ induces an equivalence relation on $X$ where $x \sim y$ if there exists some $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$. The equivalence classes of this equivalence relation are the orbits of the action, and the set of orbits is the set of equivalence classes, also known as the quotient by the equivalence relation.

Comment: I know all of that! (the set of equivalence classes, etc. all explained in Aluffi) Still I can't write $C(\Gamma) = {\{ ...}\}$ as defining set. And how $C(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))={\{ [\infty] }\}$ happened?

Comment: $C(\Gamma)$ is the set of orbits of the action of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q})$. I don't think it's particularly helpful to try writing this definition in set-builder notation, which it sounds like is what you're asking, but if you insist, here is a general definition for the set of orbits of the action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ in set-builder notation: $X/G = \{ O \subseteq X : gO = O \text{ and } \forall x, y \in O : \exists g \in G : gx = y \}$.

Comment: I still couldn't prove ${\{\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d} : \gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) }\} = \{\infty\}$.

Comment: So because the set $C(\Gamma)$ of $\Gamma-$orbits doesn't partition $\mathbb{P^1(Q)}$ to more than one set so there is one class of orbits and we denote it by ${\{ [\infty] }\}$? Am I right?