# What is the name for set of rationals including the "number" infinity?

Tags: infinity, rational-numbers

How would you write the set of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ including the number $\infty$? i.e. so it is closed under division? The set would correspond to points on a number circle.

i.e. given $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ then the pair $(a,b)$ always corresponds to a rational number $a/b$, likewise so would $(2a,2b)$ and $(-a,-b)$.

So that if two rational numbers $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are equal then $ad=bc$. (This would hold only if $\infty=-\infty$ in this set.)

Is it written as $\mathbb{Q} \cup  \infty$ ?

The rationals would seem to naturally include the point $\infty$ from the pairs $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$ etc. unless one deliberately excluded it. Whereas the set of integers doesn't include infinity.

Is there a special name for the "rational infinity?"

Comment: The mathematical structure that describes this is "the projective line over $\mathbf Q$".  It's equivalence classes of integers $[a,b]$ that are *not both zero* with $[a,b] = [c,d]$ when $ad = bc$. The equivalence class $[a,b]$ corresponds to $a/b$, so all $[0,b]$ re the same as $[0,1] = 0$ and all $[a,0]$ are the same as $[1,0] = \infty$.

Comment: Perhaps this is the "rational projective line".  The extra point is "the point at infinity".  Note: it is not closed under division.  $0/0$ and $\infty/\infty$ are still undefined.

Comment: Good point I forgot about $0/0$. Another way of saying that is $[a,b]$ where $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call it the [projective line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line) $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, as stated in the comments. It famously appears in the theory of [modular forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form#Cusp_forms) as the set of "cusps"; see, for example, [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983418/on-the-set-of-cusps-mathbbp1q).

It is not quite closed under division, but it is closed under the action of the [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group)

$$PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \left\{ z \mapsto \frac{az + b}{cz + d} : a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}, ad - bc = 1 \right\}$$

(which acts transitively), which is related to its appearance in the theory of modular forms. Of course it is also closed under the action of the slightly larger group $PGL_2(\mathbb{Q})$.